# Python HTTPServer SSL handshake hang for non-standard ports

Tags: python, ssl, freeze, handshake

I have an issue that I've been struggling with for a few days now.

I've got a simple ThreadedHTTPServer over SSL that's servicing a tiny number of requests that come over the course of a day.

Every random 10 or so connections, the server thread hangs (I have a scheduled thread that runs in parallel with the server thread but that continues to run fine while the server thread is hung).

When its hung I can't get further than the Client Hello of the SSL handshake when trying to connect with the openssl client.

```
openssl s_client -connect HOST:7813 -prexit
```

Things I've tried:

1. I thought that maybe setting a timeout on the connections would help but no cigar...yes it would timeout established connections that lingered but if the handshake is hung this had no effect.

Like:

```
class ForeMan(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
     def setup(self): 
       self.request.settimeout(1) # no

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):

   def get_request(self): #no
      ...
      sock.settimeout(1)

   def server_bind(self):#no
       ....
       self.socket.settimeout(1)
```

2. Disable the DNS resolve being performed by the BaseHTTPRequestHandler by overriding the address_string() function...probably helped a little if DNS resolution was for some reason laggy but it didn't solve the SSL handshake hang
3. I tried to check if it were perhaps the TLS versions being used but different curls with --tlv1.x did nothing to cause the hang. It only happened randomly and when certain browser clients made the request.
4. Changing the port for the HTTPServer to be 443 instead of 7813. I've searched high and low but nothing I saw in any tickets implied that this could be an issue. I guess the only thing I did note was that it is vehemently indicated that http.server for python should not be used for production...

**Resolution**

None of the above worked. For now the simplest approach is to not give Python the responsibility of handling SSL connections and delegating this to Nginx.

Comment: If it works by changing the port it is likely some middlebox (i.e. deep inspection firewall or similar) fiddling with the connection.

Comment: I think you're right...it now hung again...

Comment: I put nginx upfront and skipped the SSL nonsense altogether for now...it seems quicker already! will keep monitoring it...